# how to create those commented dividers that center text on them (they look like lines)?

Tags: ide, comments, editor, divider

In VSCode there is an extension or two that let me create those commented dividers with text centered on them.  Basically, I type some text, hit a shortcut and it wraps the text in those dashes/comments to a total predefined length. (I don't know if those things have a name or not.)

However, in Visual Studio 2019 I didn't see any extensions that let me do that.  Is there generic a way to do this in Visual Studio or any IDE/editor?  Incidentally I also use vim modes, so maybe vim can do this somehow?

[image]

Comment: This question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/415/adding-80-column-wide-comment-header-block-with-centered-text is very similar.

Comment: thanks! I'll leave this open for a while to see if there's another way and maybe if someone knows if there is a name for these things

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, and I found this VSCode extension, [Comment Divider](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stackbreak.comment-divider). I don't know if it works well with the Vim extension though.